# How to describe the smell of a stagnant pond in hot climate?

Tags: adjectives

When you have a stagnant pool of water (like a pond) in a hot climate, the water smells a bit.  Stale perhaps, but not quite reeks or stinks or foul.

How do you best describe this smell?

Comment: I avoid ponds like that, so the situation never comes up.

Comment: Your pond smells because you allowed planktonic algae to grow unchecked in it. It grows in excess because you don't have enough fish and bacteria, other whatnots to eat it. They grew because you thought was cute to allow ducks in it whose poop encouraged its growth further. Then the fermentation and hydrogen sulfide generated started killing the bacteria and little tadpoles and the fish that were supposed to eat the algae. Now you have mini-global warming catastrophe in your backyard pond that maintains a disastrous toxic stinky cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  How about "sulfric"?  Does that mean a sort of rotten-egg smell?

Answer (score 4):

For algal mosquito nurseries like that, you can either use regular words or fancy ones.  But one word that might try there is ***pungent***; it’s somewhat in the middle, neither too strong nor too weak, neither too casual nor too formal.

### **Normal words, some rather casual**

- icky
- funky
- grody
- yucky
- frowzy
- ripe
- rank
- dank
- rotten, rotting
- unsound
- gone off
- vile

### Fancier words, some rather strong

- noixous
- festering
- putrescent, putrefying
- suppurating
- purulent
- malodorous
- graveolent
- noisome
- moldering
- malarigenous, malarious
- mephitic

Answer (score 1):

The word you undoubtedly need is *fœtid*, which if you are an American you would probably spell *fetid*.

The OED shows it to be of Latin origin though the œ might have suggested to my lay person's instinct that it was from Greek.

1599   A. M. tr. O. Gaebelkhover Bk. Physicke 159/2   It maketh to blister both handes, & feet, out of which issueth foetide, and stinckinge water.

Comment: It would almost certainly have been _phoetid_ if it had been taken from Greek. :-)

Comment: The OED says that *fetid, fœtid* was adapted from “Latin *fētid-us* (often incorrectly written *fœtidus*), f. *fētēre* to have an offensive smell.”  They seem to consider it an error, but of longstanding use.  They have the same position on *fœtus, fetus*, where the OED1 even has a note reading: “The etymologically preferable spelling with *e* in this word and its cognates is adopted as the standard form in some recent Dicts., but in actual use is almost unknown.” Fortunately, this is no longer true, and *fetid, fetus* have come to dominate.

Comment: How about "rank"?

Comment: @tchrist Yes, I did notice that. But the œ is more fun, you surely have to admit! And it seems to me to add to the pungency of the fœtidness, and the mystery of the fœtus!.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **[pungent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pungent)**?

> Having a sharply strong taste or smell

[Although I like @WS2's  *fœtid*, especially with the funky typography (even though I *am* 'Meercan).]

Comment: I apologize for having beaten you to *pungent* by eleven seconds. :)

Comment: @tchrist Day nayda!

Comment: @tchrist I've got to learn to type (or at least release) faster!

Comment: Well, nobody’s gone for *pollywoggy* yet. :)

Comment: @tchrist Or *swampy*. Ribbit.

Comment: Or *boggy*, the kind of place where pollywogs do the boggy-woggy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [putrid](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Putrid) may fit:

> 1. (Biology) (of organic matter) in a state of decomposition, usually giving off a foul smell.
> 2. sickening; foul: a putrid smell.

Answer (score 0):

*Fetid* and *putrid* both strike my ear (nose?) as even stronger than *reeks, stinks, foul* (words which OP specifically says are excessive for his context).

With my BrE hat on I might say [pongy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pongy) *(giving off an unpleasant smell; stinky)*, but for a more general audience I'd say the smell was [musty,](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/musty?showCookiePolicy=true) [fusty,](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fusty?showCookiePolicy=true) or [mouldy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mouldy?showCookiePolicy=true) (US [moldy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/moldy?showCookiePolicy=true)).